# Freeform Container UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitouch

I am trying to understand if something like this is possible and if yes how can i go about achieving this.
i want to create a `UIView` that it is a container for other views that respond based on the below picture. i know that a `UIView` is a container of other UIViews. what i want to be able to do is to be able to touch on a `UIImageView` and when i am dragging it in the main View, if it gets out of bounds on one side, to be shown on exactly the opposite direction like shown on the image. i hope i managed to explain the question correctly.
[Click Here for the Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq7HK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that very easily by implementing the container `UIView`'s touch methods:

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

`- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

`- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

In `touchesMoved` you can check for your `UIImageView`'s origin. If it crosses the boundaries (`x`, `y` less than 0 or bigger than the container's dimensions) then simply reposition its frame by your desired offset.

Comment: thank you for your reply. wouldn't that snap the UIImageview to appear suddenly on the other side? i need it to be moving and showing smoothly as it moves on both sides...

Comment: so you want part of it showing on one side and the extending part on the other side?

Comment: yes it needs to be shown on the reflected side/s it can be a different instance of the same image...

Comment: yes in that case you need a duplicate image to appear from the other corner. When your main imageView goes outside frame, set the duplicate to visible and position in the position you desire (which is basically the same position as the original +/- the containers width/height). Set the parent container's `clipToBounds` to true if you dont want to imageViews to be drawn outside of its bounds.